# How do I get music onto my new laptop and the itunes i just downloaded?

Tags: data-transfer

I have 9 days worth of music on iTunes from my old laptop. How do I upload my music to the new laptop and iTunes I just downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to enable home sharing on both machines, then from your new laptop, select all the music and choose import. There are more elaborate ways if you want playlists, ratings, play counts, etc. to transfer. [This explanation](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4527) from Apple support has more information.